# Cannot create user with auto-mounted encrypted home dir in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS desktop

Tags: encryption, home-directory, automount, ecryptfs

I set up a machine with 14.04.2 and used the encrypted homedir option, which works fine from the installer. I went to move some stuff around, and ended up re-installling. I have been trying to create the same setup as the installer does, where the encrypted home dir is automounted at login.

I could not find any documentation as to how that process works, i.e. how does the login system know to mount it? Inferring from the command line tools, it look like making the user a member of the "ecryptfs" group should do it.

I am able to successfully create an encrypted homedir with the command below - note that it complains without the group option.

```
sudo adduser --ingroup ecryptfs --encrypt-home fred
```

However, even with the user as a member of the group, the automount does not occur. Also, there is no way to provide the wrapper passwords for the encyrption key passphrase.

Is there a way to see what the installer is doing different?